# Gravitational force between a point mass and two other point masses

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I want to calculate the gravitational force $F$ between a point mass $m$ and another mass $m_0=m_1+m_2$ composed of two point masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ at distances $d_1$ and $d_2$ to $m$, respectively. Here the space is assumed to be 1-dimensional for simplicity. First, $F$ can be found by superposition: $F=F_1+F_2=Gm (m_1/d_1^2+m_2/d_2^2)$

Second, can $F$ also be calculated as the force between $m$ and another point mass $m_0=m_1+m_2$ located at their center of mass (COM) $d_0=(m_1d_1+m_2d_2)/(m_1+m_2)$? Then the total force they exert on $m$ is $F'=Gm m_0/d_0^2=Gm(m_1+m_2)^3/(m_1d_1+m_2d_2)^2$, which is not equal to $F$ by the previous method.

If the second method is incorrect, how can I still apply Newton's equation $F=Gm m_0/d_0^2$, while treating $m_1$ and $m_2$ as a single mass in terms of its total mass $m_0$ and its distance $d_0$ to $m$?
Can I still find $m_0$ as the sum of $m_1$ and $m_2$? What is the right way to find $d_0$?

Comment: Why did you think that you can do that? One of the important things that Newton proved, was that a spherically symmetric distribution of mass is mathematically equivalent to a point mass at its centre; if the situation is not almost like that, then you cannot approximate the mass distribution as a point mass either. You would have to treat things to a better approximation.

Comment: Are the three masses in-line with each other?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact that my method based on the center of mass is only valid in the case of a sphere, the method cannot be generalized to arbitrary shapes such as the two point masses in my original example, as I mistakenly thought.

Answer (score 4):

Most configurations of matter do not produce a gravitational field corresponding to that of a point mass.

The exception is spherical configurations, where fortuitously everything behaves as if all the mass is in the centre and you can apply the usual force formula.

Importantly, at far distance ($d\gg |d_1-d_2|$) the force approaches $GmM/d^2$ and one can approximate it by just summing the component masses. But near the configuration it will deviate noticeably.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Yes indeed when d_1~=d_2, the two results are approximately the same F~=F'. Otherwise, the center of mass d_0 has to be replaced by the center of gravity d_CoG.

Answer (score 2):

You have highlighted the difference between centre of **mass** and centre of *gravity*.
In a uniform gravitational field those two positions are the same but in this example the gravitation field varies with position.

As an illustration, imagine equal masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ in the gravitational field of mass $m$.

[image]

The centre of mass of the two right-hand masses is midway between them.
However, since the gravitational force due to mass $m$ on mass $m_1$ is greater than that on mass $m_2$ the centre of gravity, the forces on individual masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ replaced by one force on a single mass $m_1+m_2$, will be closer to $m_1$ than it is to $m_2$.
Think of it as a weighted ([no?] pun intended) average.

As to the position of the centre of gravity you need to equate forces,

$\dfrac{Gm(m_1+m_2)}{R_{\rm CoG}^2} = \dfrac{Gm\,m_1}{r_1^2}+\dfrac{Gm\,m_2}{r_2^2}$

where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the respective distances of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ from mass $m$.

As the masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ are moved further from mass $m$, eg and $m_1$ and $m_2$ on the surface of the Earth, mass $m$, the gravitational field of the Earth over small changes of distance becomes approximately uniform and the positions of the centre of mass and centre of gravity of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ are approximately the same.

Comment: Thanks for making this clarification! I did the same by forcing the two forces to be the same, the same equation you listed above, and got the desired position, which is the center of gravity in your equation: R_CoG^2=(m_1+m_2)/(m_1/d_1^2+m_2/d_2^2)

Answer (score 1):

The two masses are not rigidly attached to each other and, even if they were, there are [quadrupole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole) and [higher order moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole#Generalization:_higher_multipoles) to consider.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that OP knows what *that* is..

Comment: @StutiGupta I am not sure so I edited my user with informative links.